# Как писать правильно: "Решение утверждено (решением?) исполкома"

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Решение утверждено Исполкомом Райсовета или
Решение утверждено решением   Исполкома Райсовета

Comment: Решение решением? Стильно!

Answer (score 3):

(1) Неясно,  как возникла ситуация, в которой одно решение утверждено другим решением. В любом случае это плохо стилистически.

(2) Если нужно указать реквизиты решения, то используют форму "утверждено решением". Например:

*УТВЕРЖДЕНО*

*Решением Президиума Совета контрольно-счетных органов при Счетной палате Российской Федерации*

*Протокол от 22 мая 2014 г. № 1-ПКСО*

В противном случае достаточно писать просто "утверждено"

(3) Слова "исполкомом райсовета" пишутся со строчной буквы.

§ 193. *Названия учреждений, учебных заведений и т. п., а также отделов и частей учреждений и организаций, не являющиеся собственными именами, пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: бюро обмена жилплощади, городское отделение связи, отдел кадров, сектор учёта, правление жилищно-строительного кооператива, **районный совет народных депутатов,** президиум, учёный совет, художественный совет, факультет журналистики, кафедра иностранных языков; то же при добавлении конкретизирующих цифр и слов: школа № 266, школа им. Маяковского, автобаза № 9, продовольственный магазин № 5, 12-я дивизия, колхоз им. Кирова*. ([Лопатин](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2/))

Comment: _М_Г: "§ 193. <...> (**Розенталь**)"_ === ??? Розенталь ли? По-моему, Вы процитировали параграф из ПАС (**Лопатин** и др.).

Comment: @slava1947. Спасибо, исправил. Это Лопатин, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

В реальных ситуациях - только первый вариант. Два слова "решение" обычно излишне. А если как у вас - без указания атрибутов и реквизитов, то избыточно абсолютно.

Ирина, я не буду спорить с М_Г, он говорит все правильно с точки зрения делопроизводства, но тут интересно и важно другое, сама ситуация, которая может предопределить появление двух слов, то есть это у М_Г первый пункт, который он не развил якобы за очевидностью.

Совершенно законно, что некий орган может принять или утвердить (или еще что-то с ним сделать) документ, который носить название "Решение" (с дополнительными словами или без, обычно - с номерами и реквизитами).

Нет ничего зазорного что процесс принятия или утверждения любого документа называется по внутреннему регламенту органа "решением". Ну например "Полстановление (такое-то) утверждено решением".

Коллизия возникает только тогда, когда обе составлящих - и документ, и процедура его принятия - называются "решением"

Если в вашем случае ничего подобного не происходит то это просто косноязычие. Поэтому в этом случае **Решение утверждено Исполкомом Райсовета** без вариантов. Не знаю, что творилось в исполкомах в пору их бытности (к тому же не уверен, что речь идет о российских реалиях), но скорее всего именно так. "Решение" просто выносится, принимается или утверждается, и это процедура решением не называется.

Хуже, когда "Решение" - это документ нижестоящего органа. Тогда формально тут два "решения" - документ и процедура. Но, думаю, даже в этом случае упомиинать о втором "решении" избыточно. И только в том не очень правдоподобном случае, когда само утверждение документа "Решение" породило некий самостоятельный документ "решение" (не должно такого быть, но "бюрократа дух силен"), без повторения слова "решения" не обойтись. Но даже в таком случае необходимо как-то обозначить разницу между двумя документнами.

**Решение Подкомиссиии [по очистке русского языка от сорных слов] утверждено решением Исполкома Райсовета от [31 мартобря 1812 г.]**

Здесь, правда, возникает другой вопрос, не с заглавной ли писать "Решение" во втором случае, в таком виде это тянет на некое условное имя собственное. По большому счету - не знаю, я бы скорее поостерегся. Но это случай, как сказал, скорее надуманный. Вопрос же о том, надо ли писать с заглавной "Исполком" и "Райсовет" выношу за скобки, похоже, тут канцеляриста не переделаешь.